# Finding Psuedo $R^2$ values from positive log-likelihood

Tags: statistics

I was using the xfrontier function on stata, and I want to find the Psuedo $R^2$ of a model using log-likelihoods. Usually, you want a negative one, so you can subtract the ratio of full v intercept model, but I got a positive one from my output.
[image]
Is there any way to derive an $R^2$ value from these numbers? I am really confused and could use some assistance.

Comment: You need to get the likelihood of the restricted model (keep a constant term only).

Comment: When I did this, it gave me a negative likelihood for the restricted model. So I'm not sure where to get the Psuedo R^2 from both of those numbers